# What are the best books for "advanced" formal logic?

Tags: logic, reference-request

There are tons of resources and books for introductory classical logic (e.g., propositional, first-order) and things to that effect. But I'm looking for something that goes beyond the basics i.e., graduate-level material in classical/non-classical logic. Does anyone have suggestions? I know that Methods of Logic by Quine is good, but I wanted to see if there were any others.

Comment: I recommend Hodges' *Shorter model theory* for classical logic and Chagrov/Zakharyaschev's *Modal logics* (it also treates intuitionistic logic and superintuitionstic logics) for nonclassical topics.

Comment: For one, Quine's *Methods of Logic* is not a graduate-level book, at least, today. If you note the subjects you have covered so far, you might get a better help.

Comment: @TankutBeygu Interesting. I’ll note that it’s a reference (non-required) book for my upcoming graduate course in formal logic. Either way, I’ve covered both propositional and first-order logic with natural deduction proofs, tautologies… basically everything covered in an “introduction to formal logic” course. I’m not sure how much this helps.

Comment: For many graduate programmes in mathematics and philosophy, Quine's book offers little material. For a transitional book see [my post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4364849/looking-for-desktop-reference-for-logic/4364875#:~:text=Elliott%20Mendelson%27s%20Introduction,just%20one%20book.)